# BPT value underlying

Tags: tokens, swaps, protocol, balancer

In Balancer, and the type of pools that work with yield tokens like Stable WETH-rETH, when `getRate()` gets called for the value of BPT, which output is in WETH,...

...does that BPT's value comes with rETH's appreciation due to staking rewards? Or BPT's appreciation is only the pool's swap fees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

> ...does that BPT's value comes with rETH's appreciation due to staking
> rewards?

It does.